# Store hash password and encrypted data with this password in db?

Tags: django, encryption, hash, passwords

I'm currently developping a django application.

I need to store user data. This data must be unavailable to any other user or admin

I've created a dedicated user account system (no using dj auth).
(Maybe I could modified it, but this is not the subject here..)

User password is hashed with passlib.

User data is encrypted using AES and user password (not hashed :p) as secret key.

I'm wondering :

- Is it safe to keep hashed password and encrypted data, when encryption used this password as secret key ?
- What can I do with AES IV used to crypt user data ? Generate it when I create the user and keep it in user table, next to hashed password ?

Comment: Questions about security or cryptography that do not include an implementation problem are off-topic for Stack Overflow. I have voted to close.

Comment: ok, i've moved to superuser